# Icefaces/JSF method call with arguments

Tags: jsf, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I'm using `Icefaces 1.8.2` and I need to do a method call with arguments on the xhtml page for which I have no idea how to do it.
My web page looks like below

```
<ice:commandLink actionListener="#{myBean.reset}">
```

MyBean looks like below

```
protected void reset(ActionEvent event, List myList) {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jsf >= 2.0:

```
<ice:commandLink actionListener="#{myBean.reset(myList)}">
```

If you just want to empty your List you can do:

```
<ice:commandLink>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.myList}" value="#{null}" />
</ice:commandLink>
```

And in your manageBean you can do something like this:

```
getMyList(){ 
    return myList == null ? new ArrayList() ? myList;
}
```

If not you can check some alternatives [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/).

Comment: I didn't want to write an extra line but I think I need to do it because I am using `WAS 7`